# How to display node in popup using modal_forms module

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

Using [Modal Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module I want to popup node content without header and footer.

I am getting many links explaining using  [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) but not with modal_forms.

Comment: The module works with forms, not nodes. Find a different module or write your own.

Comment: What actually you want ? Please update your question in detail.

Comment: I want to open node on click event